# How do I interact with UI and async functions by a button press?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have a login button that would initiate an async function `logMeIn()` for logging in, which returns a `Future<bool>` indicating if logging in was successful.

What I want to achieve is after pressing the button, the text within the button would change into a `CircularProgressIndicator`, and become plain text when `logMeIn()` has finished.

I know that I could use a `FutureBuilder` for one-time async tasks, but I simply can't think of a way to use it here.

How am I supposed to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

### Edit

I didn't provide more information because I'm pretty sure it wasn't how it's supposed to be done. But I'd share what I tried whatsoever.

My original button looks somewhat like this:

```
RaisedButton(
  child: Text("Login")
)
```

I have a async login function that returns a `Future<bool>` which indicates if the login is successful or not.

```
Future<bool> logMeIn() async {
  // login tasks here
}
```

What I want to do is to change the button to the following and run `logMeIn()` when I press the button, and change it back to the plain text version after it's finished:

```
RaisedButton(
  child: CircularProgressIndicator()
  onPressed: () {}
)
```

#### What I tried

I tried adding a `logging_in` boolean as a flag to control it, here I call the button with plain text **StaticButton()**, the other named **ActiveButton**:

Then I wrapped the ActiveButton with a `FutureBuilder`:

```
logging_in ? FutureBuilder(
  future: logMeIn(),
  builder: (_, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasData)
      setState(() {
        logging_in = false;
      });
    else
      return ActiveButton();
  }
) : StaticButton();
```

and when I pressed the button it would `setState` and set `logging_in = true`.

StaticButton:

```
RaisedButton(
  child: Text("Login"),
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      logging_in = true;
    });
  }
)
```

The above is what I tried. Should accomplish the effect, but is definitely not elegant. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Please share any relevant code.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Added details of what I tried. Looking for just a heads up on what I should be searching for, a keyword is basically enough :(

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Yup, thanks for explaining the logic. Was too focused on FutureBuilder and got lost. Your answer worked well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have isn't that far off. You have a `logging_in` variable that tells you when to show the `CircularProgressIndicator` already, which is a good start. The only thing is that `FutureBuilder` has no use here. It's meant for retrieving data from `Future`s that need to be displayed in the UI.

What you need to do is call `logMeIn` in the `onPressed` of your "Static button" as shown here:

StaticButton:

```
RaisedButton(
  child: Text("Login"),
  onPressed: () async {
    setState(() {
      logging_in = true;
    });
    await logMeIn();
    setState(() {
      logging_in = false;
    });
  }
)
```

You don't need to switch out the whole button when `logging_in` changes, just the child of the button.

StaticButton(with child switching):

```
RaisedButton(
  child: logging_in ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text("Login"),
  onPressed: () async {
    setState(() {
      logging_in = true;
    });
    await logMeIn();
    setState(() {
      logging_in = false;
    });
  }
)
```

You also probably want to add another `bool` to prevent multiple clicks of the button while its loading. As a note in using `FutureBuilder` and essentially any other `builder` in flutter, you always need to return a widget from the `builder` function, which your current implementation does not do.